# Excel formula and calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to keep a spreadsheet of the statistics about FIFA soccer matches in my competition.
We have three players and every week we play 6 games (2 each)

***Week 0 statistics:***

[image]

I am trying to get Totals goals conceded in Games lost.

I have the players set up as X VS X and then to the right of it the goals scored in the game.
Then next to that I have a section where I put the first initial of the player who won under Wins and the player who lost under Lost.

My problem is that The player does not always show up on the side of the final result.

Such as Mike Vs Paul 3-6  Wins/P  Loses/M

Here mike is on the left side and paul is on the Right but in the decision section it is mike on the right and paul on the left

How would I formulate an equation to total all the goals that mike has conceded in the games that he has lost and in the games that he has won?

[image: Updated table]

Answer (score 0):

Alex, with an excel file structure you currently have, it is not sustainable to keep track of games or similar things.  What you should do is creating a data table like below, and inputting your results into this.  This data table will give you the opportunity to create summaries (over this data table) like you want via a pivot table, or a basic dashboard in which you will use formulas like `sumifs`, `vlookup` etc.

Please give it a try and come back later if you got stuck.

[image]

Comment: Ok i have set it up the way you have it set up. I updated my question and posted a new pictrue. How would i find the goals that Paul conceded in his 4 games @ozgun Senyuva

Comment: What formula did you use for the goals Paul scored ?